# How do I express दिल लगाना in English? It literally means 'attaching heart.'

Tags: word-request, verbs, idioms, adjectives, nouns

I am Indian, not a native English speaker.

I can't figure out the English expression. We Indians use **दिल लगाना** literal translation  '**to attach heart**' which implies to be in love with someone in Hindi. Please help me to understand this or provide other English expressions that implies to be in love

For example:

> He has attached his heart to her,  now he cannot live without her because he loves her so much

Comment: Well, it fits the meaning, but it is a little unusual. We are more likely to say that you *give* your heart to someone.

Comment: I think if it weren't in the present perfect, "He attached his heart to her," sounds rather poetic.

Comment: If you want to be poetic about attaching something, have a look at _entwined_

Comment: @joiedevivre  I don't know.  "He attached his heart to her" sounds to me more *surgical* than *romantic*.  I prefer mplugjan's more natural "their hearts were *entwined*".

Comment: How about "He is lovesick for or with her" ?

Comment: @Andrew I would argue that good poetry is more likely to use surprising language than more natural-sounding language, although entwined is a nice word, too! You also have a point about the potential surgical nature of it. I could certainly see it going the way of I Hold Your Hand in Mine (http://www.lyricsfreak.com/t/tom+lehrer/i+hold+your+hand+in+mine_20138407.html).

Comment: considering the varying levels of intensity, what about "he pulled on her heart strings", ro "she pulled on his heart strings"... as it can be love, or pity, or an heartfelt emotion...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*दिल लगाना* has ***nothing*** to do with love! Rather, you can consider that as [*मन बहलाना*](https://en.bab.la/dictionary/hindi-english/%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B2-%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE).

The meaning of this phrase in Hindi changes according to the usage of it in a sentence. Study this:

> उसका वहा पे दिल नही लगता| (Literal translation: her heart is not attached/involved there) - She's *not happy* there!

So, yes, in a way, you *attach your heart* with something or someone you like. But it is **not always** love.

If you want to talk about the *intensity* of love, there are many ways. One such way is:

> He loves her so deeply that he cannot live without her.

---

For non-native speakers of *Hindi,* we have this idiom to talk about *one's heart being happy* doing something or being with someone. That *something/one* could be animate or inanimate object. दिल (pronounced: dee-l) means *heart*, and लगाना (pronounced: la-gaa-naa) means *attached*. Together they translate: heart attached/involved.

Comment: If the correct answer to the question is to explain something about the Hindi language, shouldn't the question be migrated to the Hindi Language Stack? (Which, unfortunately, doesn't exist)

Comment: @ThePhoton yes, it should be migrated but there's no Hindi Stack. ***BUT*** I have seen a dozen questions asking for [English expression translating *Chinese*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/123862/can-we-say-transformation-and-upgrading-were-accelerated) here! And, they get upvotes too! And, we have separate Chinese Stack as well!

Comment: @MaulikV  I agree the question itself is fine, but I don't approve your answer which focuses as much on the use of the Hindi phrase as on the various ways to express this in English.  A good answer should start with an accurate translation, and then add natural-sounding English variations.

Comment: @Andrew the OP should be *informed first* that the expression what she writes *does not mean* what she thinks! That's how the answer **should be** overcoming the misunderstanding. It's okay for your disapproval! :)

Comment: @MaulikV  as a comment, sure.  As an answer, it feels off-topic.

Comment: I think with a little more explanation for non-Hindi speakers of the HIndi (especially in the first sentence) this would be a fine answer. I think it is an important addition because it addresses the nuance of the phrase being asked about. The problem is it doesn't explain that nuance very well in English, so I can't really understand it.

Comment: I like your answer, Maulik, but I agree with Colleen. As a non-Hindi speaker, I find it interesting when say that the phrase has many meanings based on its usage -- maybe you can give some examples? Eg "if you use like like *this*, which has a literal translation of *that*, then the appropriate idiom/phrase in English is *something*. But if you use it *some other way*..."

Comment: @Maulik V :  मन बहलाना literally means' to entice heart'.  Hindi and English in both languages , the Entice implies to provoke someone or something to do something through (often flase or exaggerated) promises or persuasion

Comment: The hindi example your provided dosent work in the way you explain or suits the example which I ask above

Comment: Of course @Ziyabano it won't suit what you asked because both are different! That's what I wrote. In short, 'dil lagana' is ***not always*** in the context of love. And, you asked that how to say it in English, so my English version is also there.

Answer (score 12):

That isn't an idiomatic expression in English, but it's not weird, and the meaning is quite clear. In fact, it's rather pretty.

The closest idiomatic expression in English might be "He had his heart set on her." But you could use that in contexts where you weren't in love. For example, "he had his heart set on the prize" would mean getting the prize was very important to him.

I like your expression better.

Comment: Can you say _He had lost his heart to her_ in this context?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes, that's certainly another valid expression, and nicer-sounding than "set his heart on her!" You would leave out "had" though (not use past perfect), unless you were comparing two past events. For example, "she fell in love with him in 2010, but he had lost his heart to her long before then."

Answer (score 9):

The most similar English idiom to your provided one would be:

> He has given her his heart

Similarly you can say "his heart belongs to her."

---

Here's some more soppy romance stuff:

- she stole his heart
- he has given himself to her
- his heart is no longer his [to command]

etc.

Comment: Or just "she stole my heart".

Answer (score 4):

If the question is about idiomatic expressions of love, any of the following would be candidates:

- She is the apple of his eye.
- She is head over heels about him.
- He takes her breath away.
- He fancies her.
- He has eyes only for her.
- She is smitten by him.
- They are going steady.
- They are a match made in heaven.
- *etc.*

To say, "he attached his heart to her," isn't specifically known as an idiomatic expression of love, but it would generally work since it doesn't idiomatically refer to anything other specific thing.

Answer (score 3):

The closest that I can think of is **to find a way into someone's heart**.

Example:

> When he proposed to her the first time, he got rejected. But he didn't give up and later was able to finally **find a way into her heart** and make her love him.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to express a similar sentiment in English would be:

> She **stole my heart**, I cannot live without her.

Answer (score 0):

To catch is more common than attach in that context, a catch is also the hook on a door. You can catch someone's eye, and catch someone's fancy, and yet hearts are rarely caught. They are bewitched, charmed, stolen, put under a spell.

There are other very useful words other than attach, *Snag* and *Hitch* *laced up*, *captured*, *bridled*, and you may use litterary licence and use a new combination of word which pleases you and coin a new term. Ensnared is a gothic way of saying it, and laced up is a figurative one.

In french they also say accroche-coeur very often and coup-de-coeur.